# ExtJS 4 Getter method for controller stores

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In my controller I define related stores like

```
stores: [
    'devices.DevicesStore',
    'devicegroups.DeviceGroupsStore'
],
```

Is there any automatically generated getters for defined stores with "namespaces" (`devices.` and `devicegroups.` as in example above)? How I can get this stores in my `init` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter name is generated by the [`getGetterName`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/source/Controller2.html#Ext-app-Controller-static-method-getGetterName) function:

> ```
> getGetterName: function(name, kindUpper) {
>         var fn       = 'get',
>             parts    = name.split('.'),
>             numParts = parts.length,
>             index;
>
>         // Handle namespaced class names. E.g. feed.Add becomes getFeedAddView etc.
>         for (index = 0; index < numParts; index++) {
>             fn += Ext.String.capitalize(parts[index]);
>         }
>
>         fn += kindUpper;
>
>         return fn;
>     }
> ```